# I Don't Understand Error Bounds

Tags: calculus, integration

I understand they're supposed to give us a limit on how off our approximation of an integral can be, but I don't understand how the formula gives that.

[image]

What does the second derivative have to do with anything? Why are the constants 12 and 24 put in front of $n^2$? I'm really looking for an explanation as to why this formula gives us error bounds.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftutorial.math.lamar.edu%2FClasses%2FCalcII%2FApproximatingDefIntegrals.aspx&ei=7L6xU8M8iuzxAeHFgNAD&usg=AFQjCNGhuoKrFb5vMyWy1CLrHTHGW1GHPg&sig2=XyRInBf6jT9IAJPfZuy6GA

Comment: The formulas have been proven to be true. [Here](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/An_Elementary_Proof30705.pdf) is one proof of the error formula for the Trapezoidal Rule. Other proofs for both rules can be found elsewhere (but usually not in texts for a first course); e.g., in Bartle and Sherbert's *Introduction to Real Analysis* (even here, the proofs are relegated to an appendix). I won't venture to guess why the particular constants should not seem  mysterious (if in fact this is the case).

Comment: See this [Table Page](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_885.htm).

Comment: To see why it's not surprising that the second derivative shows up, remember that the midpoint/trapezoid rules will give *exactly* the correct value for straight lines.  In some sense, the second derivative is a measure of how far a function is from being a straight line.

Comment: As for what the second derivative has to do with it, notice that the trapezoidal and midpoint rules are exact for linear functions, that is, those with second derivative equal to zero.  So the second derivative keeps track of how far the function strays from linear on the interval.  If you used a higher-order rule, that exactly integrated parabolas, then the third derivative would come into play.  To see what the constants come from, I think the worst case is just a parabola, so you can check the error directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a derivation of the error bound for the midpoint rule.

The midpoint rule is

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx \approx \frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}f(\bar{x}_j),$$

where $x_j = a + j(b-a)/n$ and $\bar{x}_j = (x_{j-1}+x_j)/2.$

The absolute error is

$$E = \left|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx - \frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}f(\bar{x}_j)\right| = \left|\sum_{j=1}^{n}\int_{x_{j-1}}^{x_{j}}[f(x)-f( \bar{x}_j)]dx \right|.$$

Using Taylor's theorem,

$$f(x) = f(\bar{x}_j)+f'(\bar{x}_j)(x-\bar{x}_j) + \frac1{2}f''(\xi_x)(x-\bar{x}_j)^2,  $$

where $\xi_x$ is between $x$ and $\bar{x}_j$ and $|f''(\xi_x)| \leq K$.

Substituting and integrating we get

$$E =  \left|\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac1{2}\int_{x_{j-1}}^{x_{j}}f''( \bar{x}_j)(x-\bar{x}_j)^2dx \right| \\ \leq \frac1{2}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\int_{x_{j-1}}^{x_{j}}|f''( \bar{x}_j)|(x-\bar{x}_j)^2dx  \leq \frac{K}{24}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(x_j-x_{j-1})^3 = \frac{K}{24}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(\frac{b-a}{n}\right)^3\\= \frac{K(b-a)^3}{24n^2}$$

Comment: Your solution made my day! Thanks

Comment: @FarhadRouhbakhsh: You're welcome. I'm glad this was helpful.

Answer (score -1):

These formulas are methods for **approximating** integrals.

Because the actual answer isn't the answer obtained by using simpson's rule, trapezoidal rule, etc.

We allocate for that **difference** by using a formula to calculate that difference.

We use this difference to then see how close our value is to the accepted value.

This is useful application in both physics and mathematics.

Comment: I believe the OP is asking how these formulae are derived.

Comment: The original post asks several specific questions, none of which you tried to answer. Instead, you explained the part that OP says they already understand.